# Is it possible to set an object's origin with bpy.ops.transform.resize()?

Tags: python, scale, origin

I would like to scale an object with object's origin in a certain location. Is it possible to set an object's origin with bpy.ops.transform.resize()?

I’ve examined the official [API documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.ops.transform.html?highlight=bpy%20ops%20transform%20resize#bpy.ops.transform.resize), but method explanations are still quite scarce.

As far as I understand, there should be an option to set a pivot in float numbers (either in local or global coordininates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "center_override" for this. Here is the code:

```
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(1, 1, 1), center_override=(42, 42, 42))
```

Happy Blending! :)

Comment: Thanks! What kind of coordinates does this argument use? Global or local? Or should I use 'constraint_orientation' to specify it?